# how do you punctuate: father son act

Tags: punctuation

How would you properly punctuate this??

1)The father, son act of Bob and Jim

2)The father-son act of Bob and Jim

or

3)The father/son act of Bob and Jim

Comment: Please specify the meaning of the sentence that you want so that we can help to punctuate this.

Comment: I would write it as *the father-and-son act*, where "father-and-son" acts as multiple-word adjective. The use of a slash in 3) is also a stylistic choice that could be used; however, I suspect it's less common. Not using any punctuation at all and just writing "the father and son act" would be understandable, but it would look a bit awkward in the context of the rest of the sentence.

Answer (score 1):

The purpose here is to join the words "father" and "son" into a single compound, that will describe the noun "act".

A comma creates a division, but we want to join these words. A comma won't work here

The slash can mean "and", but slashes are usually avoided in formal writing [source](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/slash.html). You could use the slash, however...

The hyphen is used for joining compound words, which is exactly what we want. That would be the clearest choice here.

> The father-son act...